# getting UIImageView names

Tags: iphone, xcode, object, properties

In my app i have header file that has five different UIImageViews that need to be placed on another five stationary UIImageViews.

So five that never move and five that user places on the stationary ones.  Stationary ones are in an array called posArray and the other movable five are also in an array.

So now user goes and touches the movable ones and drags them on static ones.  If movable one collides with static one, movable object's x,y become static's x,y.

The question i have is how can i tell which movable object is touching which static object?

Is movableObj1 touching staticObj1 or staticObj2 or which one?  The movable ones can be put anywhere so i'm not sure how to get the names of them once they are touching.

The code below is what makes a movable array stick to the static array if they touch.  Movable objects can be placed in any of the five static ones.

```
for (int i = 0; i < [posArray count]; i++) {

    UIImageView *tempPos;
    tempPos = [posArray objectAtIndex:i];

    if (CGRectIntersectsRect(tempPlayer.frame, tempPos.frame)) {

        tempPlayer.center = CGPointMake(tempPos.center.x, tempPos.center.y);
    }

}
```

Comment: you can set the tag for each UIImageview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you need to assign tag to each Uiimageview. So it's easier for you to identify which imageview you are moving.